# Is it possible to set CPU speed with Tasker?

Tags: tasker, setcpu

For example: I would like to set my CPU to higher end for when running a specific application, such as psx4droid.  Is this possible with Tasker?

Or if not Tasker... any other app?  SetCPU doesn't have the option.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you could get there by having tasker either directly set the system variables necessary to overclock or to access the commands that setCPU uses.  To do that you can use the "Execute" plugin that executes commands like you would in the terminal emulator.  A lot of this is over my head but you probably understand terminal commands and such better and may be able to make sense of my ramblings:

1. Install the [Locale Execute Plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locale-execute-plug-in/de.elmicha.app.LocaleExecute)
2. Create a new profile for when you run psx4droid
3. Add a task to set the CPU
4. Add an action and choose Plugin/Execute
5. Execute the command necessary to reset(overclock) the CPU.  Here's a [link to explain how to format the commands](http://tasker.wikidot.com/rootbasic). Unfortunately I don't know what command does this.

Theoretically, when you open psx4droid it should run that profile you created, changing the CPU settings.

Comment: Google search on "Locale Execute Setcpu" turned up this result from Reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/ea7cq/overunderclocking_setcpu/

Comment: Ha! Perfect! Let me know if it works.  I didn't realize there was a Tasker devoted subreddit.

Answer (score -1):

Try this thread on XDA [Tasker CPU Control Profiles](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1018245)

Comment: And what will one find when they follow that link? Answers of nothing but a link to another site are generally not useful. What happens if that link stops working?